# How to write code to do conditional template instantiation in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a class template that is parametrized on size_t,

```
template<size_t k>
class MyClass {...}
```

The parameter k should really be less than 10, in this case and I would like it to fail to compile if it goes beyond that. How can I do that in C++11 and above?

```
MyClass<1> instance1; // ok
MyClass<2> instance2; // ok
MyClass<100> instance100; // fail to compile
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `static_assert`

```
template<size_t k>
class MyClass {
    static_assert(k < 10, "Illegal k");
};

int main() {
  MyClass<50> t; //< Compile time failure
}
```

Comment: You can put `static_assert` into the class body as well. With your way only the ctor calls will fail to compile which may or may not be what OP wants.

Comment: Updated. The solution. Yes, you are right, I can put the `static_assert` anywhere in the class.

Comment: I voted for this answer. While I find SFINAE (e.g. `std::enable_if`) very funny to use, it is less readable and the compile-time error is not as clear as what you can get with `static_assert`.

Answer (score 5):

You could add a check in the template parameter like

```
template<size_t k, std::enable_if_t<k <= 10, bool> = true>
class MyClass {};
```

This will allow `MyClass<1> instance1;` but `MyClass<100> instance100;` will fail to compile.

Comment: I'm very curious why anyone would use this technique; it seems to me that cplusplusrat's `static_assert()` technique is much more straightforward and understandable than this technique. Also I'm not familiar with `std::enable_if_t<>`, can you add an explanation of how this accomplishes what the OP needs? What about it makes `MyClass<100>` fail to compile?

Comment: @phonetagger If you&#39;re doing some more complex meta programming, `enable_if` gives you way more opportunities. E.g. it is common to enable certain function overloads for some template parameters and some other overloads for others. But in this particular use case I see no reason to prefer it over `static_assert`, as you say.

Comment: @L.F. I've updated the answer to use a `bool`.  I've been working through answer but missed this one.

Comment: @NathanOliver Never mind, this is being neglected all the time and no compiler actually diagnoses this at all.

Comment: @L.F. No, they don't.  I've heard from some people some compilers will error, but the major ones don't and I guess that is a good thing as there are so many resources that do it the `void*` way.  FWIW all of my new code I use `enable_if_t<..., boo> = true` to compliance proof the code.  Won't matter for much longer but I like seeing the `true` as it reminds me this is only enabled when the condition is true.

Comment: @NathanOliver Wow, really.  I was testing only GCC and Clang and claimed that nobody diagnoses that ...  I guess I am gonna update my https://stackoverflow.com/q/56003162, but later ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::enable_if` if you are using C++11.

```
template<std::size_t k, typename unused = typename std::enable_if<k <= 10>::type>
class MyClass {};
```

You can use `std::enable_if_t` if you are able to use C++14 or higher.

```
template<std::size_t k, typename unused = std::enable_if_t<k <= 10 >>
class MyClass {};
```

Comment: I'm very curious why anyone would use these techniques; it seems to me that cplusplusrat's `static_assert()` technique is much more straightforward and understandable than either of these techniques. Also I'm not familiar with `std::enable_if<>` or `std::enable_if_t<>`, can you add an explanation of how these accomplish what the OP needs?

Comment: You'll have to lookup SFINAE in C++. Here's a starting page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae.

Comment: Figuring out how SFINAE and `std::enable_if<>` or `std::enable_if_t<>` work is hard enough; it would still be helpful to add a couple sentences explaining the essence of how that accomplishes what the OP needs, even if you leave out the details. Scott Meyers would never have sold more than a few books if he didn't write in a way that was understandable to his readers. SO is not supposed to be a technical reference site for people who are already language experts; it's supposed to be more helpful than that.

Comment: @phonetagger Unfortunately, SFINAE is generally considered a very basic part of C++ that is expected to be covered in primers.

Comment: Also, an (over) intelligent user can hijack this solution by explicitly providing a second argument.