# Can a non-type template parameter be of type "void*"?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, c++20

[**Yakk - Adam Nevraumont**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667)
[said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53922811):

> Non-type template parameters of type `void*` are not allowed in at
>   least some versions of the standard.

Is this true?
If it is true, in which versions of the standard are non-type template parameters of type `void*` not allowed?

(Note: as noted in
[a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003162/can-a-non-type-template-parameter-be-of-type-void/56003163#comment98660308_56003163)
to answer
[another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003162/can-a-non-type-template-parameter-be-of-type-void/56003163#comment98660107_56003163),
this is about **non-type template parameters**,
not *template type arguments*,
which can be any valid *type-id* per
[[temp.arg.type]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.type#1),
including `void*`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## TL;DR

Template parameters of type `void*` are valid since C++20.
They are invalid prior to C++20.

## C++20

C++20 relaxed the restrictions on the type of a non-type template parameter,
so let's investigate it first.

The current draft (as of UTC 10:00, May 6, 2019) says in [[temp.param]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#4):

> A non-type *template-parameter* shall have one of the following
>   (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - a literal type that has *strong structural equality* ([class.compare.default]),
> - an lvalue reference type,
> - a type that contains a placeholder type ([dcl.spec.auto]), or
> - a placeholder for a deduced class type ([dcl.type.class.deduct]).

`void*` is a pointer type.
A pointer type is a *scalar type* ([[basic.types]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#def:scalar_type)).
A *scalar type* is a *literal type* ([[basic.types]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#def:literal_type)).
Therefore, `void*` is a *literal type*.
The first bullet is the relevant one.

Tracking down further, [[class.compare.default]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.compare.default#3) says:

> A type `C` has *strong structural equality* if, given a glvalue `x` of
>   type `const C`, either:
>
> - `C` is a non-class type and `x <=> x` is a valid expression of type `std::strong_ordering` or `std::strong_equality`, or
> - `C` is a class type with an `==` operator defined as defaulted in the definition of `C`, `x == x` is well-formed when contextually
>     converted to `bool`, all of `C`'s base class subobjects and non-static
>     data members have strong structural equality, and `C` has no `mutable`
>     or `volatile` subobjects.

`void*` is a non-class type,
so the first bullet is relevant.
Now the question boils down to the type of `x <=> x`
where `x` is a glvalue of type `void* const` (not `const void*`).
Per [[expr.spaceship]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.spaceship#8):

> If the composite pointer type is an *object pointer type*, `p <=> q` is
>   of type `std::strong_­ordering`. If two pointer operands `p` and `q`
>   compare equal ([expr.eq]), `p <=> q` yields
>   `std::strong_­ordering::equal`; if `p` and `q` compare unequal, `p <=>
>   q` yields `std::strong_­ordering::less` if `q` compares greater than
>   `p` and `std::strong_­ordering::greater` if `p` compares greater than
>   `q` ([expr.rel]). Otherwise, the result is unspecified.

Note that `void*` is an *object pointer type* ([[basic.compound]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#def:object_pointer_type)).
Therefore, `x <=> x` is of type `std::strong_ordering`.
Thus the type `void*` has *strong structural equality*.

Therefore, **in the current C++20 draft,
`void*` is allowed as the type of a template parameter type.**

## C++17

Now we address C++17.
[[temp.param]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#4) says:

> A non-type *template-parameter* shall have one of the following
>   (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - integral or enumeration type,
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> - pointer to member,
> - `std​::​nullptr_­t`, or
> - a type that contains a placeholder type.

Note that "pointer to object" doesn't include `void*`
per [[basic.compound]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#3):

> [ *Note:* A pointer to `void` does not have a pointer-to-object type, however, because `void` is not an object type. — *end note* ]

None of the above six bullets include `void*`
as a possible type of a template parameter.
Therefore, in C++17,
a template parameter shall not have type `void*`.

The wording is the same for C++11 and C++14
except that the bullet about placeholder types are not there.
In general,
**prior to C++20,
a template parameter shall not have type `void*`.**

## But do compilers diagnose this?

[T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719) says in a
[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003162/can-a-non-type-template-parameter-be-of-type-void/56003163#comment98659377_56003163)
that nobody diagnoses this IHRC.
Let's test whether compilers diagnose that in C++17 mode
with the minimal example shown below:

```
template <void*>
class C {};

int main()
{
    C<nullptr> x;
    (void) x;
}
```

The code compiles and runs fine on
[GCC 9.1.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PcFPMyccmOXdYSeD),
[GCC 8.3.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kZuY9EyTB8dVSAJc),
[GCC 7.3.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/64h3aCljXQyZ62Hk),
[GCC 6.3.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q9S6yXnlBz9moqRY),
[GCC 5.5.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Is4feDiMifCXPrzE),
[Clang 8.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/R8FGvCUGBH0Dcjla),
[Clang 7.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1cA1upIVbZXCG678),
[Clang 6.0.1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2gCwrQfCHC2vPzwN),
and [Clang 5.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mXx0lMEVfv3Fra0b).

[NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498) told me in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52105822/how-to-write-code-to-do-conditional-template-instantiation-in-c/52105877?noredirect=1#comment100744721_52105877) that someone told him some compilers will error, but the major ones don't.  Therefore, as far as I am able to confirm here, T.C.'s statement is correct — nobody diagnoses this.

Comment: Nobody diagnoses that though IIRC.

Comment: What is this even saying? I have always been able to do `vector<void*>`.

Comment: @Joshua This is about `template <void*> struct X { };` -- not about `template <typename T> struct Y { }; Y<void*>();`