# combination of enable_if + std::less + sizeof... makes MSVC fail

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Here is an extremely simple code :

```cpp
template <typename... Args,
 typename std::enable_if<std::less<int>()(sizeof...(Args), 3), int>::type* = nullptr>
void test(std::tuple<Args...>)
{

}

int main()
{
    test(std::make_tuple(1, 2));
}
```

It's just simple function template with some `enable_if` condition. (for further SFINAE).

But **it fails to compile** in **Visual Studio 2019 with C++ 17** setup.

```
error C2672:  'test': no matching overloaded function found
error C2783:  'void test(std::tuple<_Types...>)': could not deduce template argument for '__formal'
```

However I found that **it compiles well in GCC and Clang**. Why does that seemingly innocent code fail?

funny thing is if I substitute `sizeof...(Args)` to `2` then it suddenly works.

**Edit** : My original question doesn't provide type in `enable_if`, but I found that `void*` is not allowed as a non-type template parameter in C++ 17. **But It doesn't matter.** Because even if I change to `std::enable_if<std::less<int>()(sizeof...(Args), 3), int>`, **it still fails with same error.**

Comment: Why not just `sizeof...(Args) < 3`, anyway? ;-)

Comment: Note that `void*` non-type template parameters are not allowed in C++17.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56003162

Comment: @L.F. wow, I didn't know that. But I think MSVC is still wrong (or at least inconsistent) because it works if I change ``sizeof`` to ``2``.

Comment: Yep, that's nothing more than a coincidental correctness resulted from two mistakes.

Comment: [It does work](https://godbolt.org/z/_7DXmd) if you change the template to an anonymous type instead of a non-type, interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Per [[comparisons.less]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/comparisons.less):

> ```
> template <class T = void> struct less {
>   constexpr bool operator()(const T& x, const T& y) const;
> };
> ```
>
> ```
> constexpr bool operator()(const T& x, const T& y) const;
> ```
>
> *Returns:* `x < y`.

The operator is `constexpr`.  Therefore, your code is fine as far as the `less` is concerned.

However, technically speaking, MSVC is actually right here — non-type template parameters shall not have type `void*` in C++17.  MSVC actually diagnosed that.  That's purely a coincidence, anyway.

You can use `<` directly as a workaround:

```
template <typename... Args,
  typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Args) < 3), int>::type = 0>
void test(std::tuple<Args...>)
```

(Note that `int` is used instead of `void*`, so that a language pedant has absolutely nothing to say.)

Comment: Thanks. I already knew how to solve this problem, but my question is rather "what makes this simple code fail in MSVC ??"

Comment: @i.stav MSVC is known to fail mysteriously at times ;-)

Comment: well, it still fails if I provide ``int`` to ``enable_if`` but still keeping ``std::less``. So MSVC is completely wrong