# enable_if + is_same + constexpr function makes MSVC fail (but works well in Clang, GCC)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer

Here's an extremely simple code:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>

template <class T> struct TypeHolder {};

template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t array_size(TypeHolder<std::array<T,N>>)
{
    return N;
};

using AnyType = int;
template <class V, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<V,
 std::array<typename V::value_type, array_size(TypeHolder<V>())>>::value, AnyType>::type* = nullptr>
    void test(V & v)
{

}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 5> x;
    test(x);
}
```

Don't ask what the hell this code is for. It doesn't matter. It's just refined and simplified example of what I found. The important thing is it seems to be valid C++ 17 code anyway.

`test()` is enabled (in further SFINAE situation) only when V is `std::array`. Yeah, I know that I can just do `template<class T, int N> void test(array<T, N>& v)` but this more dirty template parameters help me in some cases for not having `int N`. (Trust me!)

Anyway this C++ 17 **code fails to compile in Visual Studio 2019** with C++ 17 setup.
However **it works well in GCC and Clang.**

Hours ago, I posted related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56880663/combination-of-enable-if-stdless-sizeof-makes-msvc-fail).
The only thing I could found in common is that they're about some complicated templates and that they result in same error codes :

```
error C2672:  no matching overloaded function found
error C2783:  could not deduce template argument for '__formal'
```

Questions are....

1. Is that a valid C++ 17 code?
2. Then why does MSVC fail to compile?
3. What is the relation with my previous question?
4. How should I deal with this if I decided to just use MSVC?

Comment: By the way, is there a special reason that you are still using `::value` and `::type` instead of the `_t`s and `_v`s?

Comment: @L.F. I know what you're saying about. **But** I can overload ``array_size()`` and always choose ``V`` that has ``value``. After I add some other ``test()``s then it becomes completely typical SFINAE overloading resolution. (not a hard error)

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong.  Deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @L.F. That's ok. (I appreciate your interest on this question) BTW what are ``_t`` and ``_v``?

Comment: For example, you can write `enable_if_t<xxx>` in place of `typename enable_if<xxx>::type`, and `is_same_v<yyy>` in place of `is_same<yyy>::value`.

Comment: Interestingly enough, rewriting the function in a different way allows compilation: https://godbolt.org/z/mDPPq7

Comment: Looks like a regression, since the code works in VS 2017 15.9.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what exactly is tripping MSCV's compiler but the replacing default pointer with a default type parameter seems to work:

```
template <typename V, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<V,
 std::array<typename V::value_type, array_size(TypeHolder<V>())>>, AnyType>>
    void test(V & v)
```

Both should be valid C++17 as the second argument can be deduced from the `V`. Perhaps the constexpr functions are not as per the standard in MSCV yet.

Comment: Thanks. I think there's something for MSVC in situation of ``constexpr function call as non-type argument`` + ``enable_if_t<>*``